# How to get the anchor tag link and name using URL?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, breadcrumbs

I have a URL

```
https://example.com/test/test1/test1_1/test1_2/
```

I am using the script below to get all the page names like breadcrumbs

```
 var current = location.pathname.slice(1).split('/').join(' > ');
//Output: test > test1 > test1_1 > test1_2 >
```

Is there a way I can get along with the anchor tag? I have to set the click event. I have tried the code below

```js
var current = location.pathname.slice(1).split('/').join(' > ');


$('#nav_menu-2').prepend('<div id="menu-breadcrumb"></div>');
var menuBreadcrumb = document.getElementById('menu-breadcrumb');

$('#nav_menu-2 li a').each(function() {
  var $this = $('#nav_menu-2 li a');

  var thismenuLi = $($this).parent().attr('id');
  let thismenuText = $($this).text();

  var shortText = jQuery.trim(thismenuText).substring(0, 15)
    .split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";


  let mbcElement = '<a class="mbc-link-back" href="#" data-menu-item-id="' + thismenuLi + '">' + shortText + '</a>'
  menuBreadcrumb.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', mbcElement);

});
```

```html
<div class="secondary">
  <div id="menu-breadcrumb"></div>
  <nav class="nav" id="nav_menu-2">
    <ul id="menu-inner-page-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-204" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-304" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Test 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-401" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Test 1.2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#link">Test 1.2.1</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: (To add to that - messages to ingratiate, plead, beg, nag, or cajole for assistance generally do not help, and they may even attract downvotes. It really is best to keep it succinct).

Comment: "*Is there a way I can get along with the anchor tag?*" - I don't know what this means in terms of your question; what do you want your code to do?